# Transform integer into string for readability using PHP

Tags: php, string

How to transform, for example:

10 -> 10
1000 -> 1,000
10000000000 -> 10,000,000,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.